# Unable to access props in HOC's class function but able to access them in render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-component

*What I'm trying to achieve:* 
I have many forms and I want to keep form validation logic in my HOC so that I don't have to repeat validation logic as most forms would have same fields and some extra or less fields.

*How I have Implemented:*

Learning to create HOC, followed this example [HOC example](https://medium.com/@bosung90/use-higher-order-component-in-react-native-df44e634e860) and tried to create an HOC like below.

```
import React from 'react';
import {
    spaceCheck,
    specialCharacterCheck,
    numberValidator
} from '../../utility/validators';

const fieldHOC = (WrappedComponent) => {
    class HOC extends React.Component {
            state = {
                error: {
                    name_first: {
                        fieldType: 'name_first',
                        errorType: 0
                    },
                    name_last: {
                        fieldType: 'name_last',
                        errorType: 0
                    },
                    email: {
                        fieldType: 'email',
                        errorType: 0
                    }
                }
            };

    getErrorMessage = (fieldType, errorType) => {
        this.setState({
            error: {
                ...this.state.error,
                [fieldType]: {
                    ...this.state.error[fieldType],
                    errorType
                }
            }
        });
    };

    checkFieldsError = (currentFocus, nextFocus) => {
       //Not able to get props passed by below component in class functions
        console.log('MY PROPS', this.props);
        const field = this.props[currentFocus];
        if (field === '' || spaceCheck(field)) {
            this.getErrorMessage(currentFocus, 1);
        } else if (specialCharacterCheck(field)) {
            this.getErrorMessage(currentFocus, 2);
        } else if (numberValidator(field) || numberValidator(field)) {
            this.getErrorMessage(currentFocus, 3);
        } else {
            this.setState({
                error: {
                    ...this.state.error,
                    [currentFocus]: {
                        ...this.state.error[currentFocus],
                        errorType: 0
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        this[nextFocus].focus();
    }
    render() {
        const { children } = this.props;
         // Here able to access props(name_first, name_last and email) passed from below component 
        // console.log('PROPS', this.props);
        return (
            <WrappedComponent
                {...this.props}
                error={this.state.error}
                checkFieldsError={this.checkFieldsError}
            >
                {children}
            </WrappedComponent>
        );
    }
    }
    return HOC;
};

export default fieldHOC;
```

Component in which I'm using this HOC is

```
 const FieldValidation = fieldHOC(View);
    class Account extends Component {
        //Some class functions
      render() {
        const { spaceBottom, error } = this.state;
        return (
         <KeyboardAvoidingView
                        style={{ flex: 1 }}
                        keyboardShouldPersistTaps="handled"
                        behavior={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 'padding' : null}
                    >
                        <KeyboardAwareScrollView
                            keyboardShouldPersistTaps="handled"
                            alwaysBounceVertical={false}
                            contentInset={{ bottom: 0 }}
                        >
                          <FieldValidation
                                name_first={this.state.name_first}
                                name_last={this.state.name_last}
                                email={this.state.email}
                                {...this.props}
                            >
                               <View
                                    style={[
                                        styles.UserContainer,
                                        CommonStyle.shadowStyle
                                    ]}
                                >
                                    <Text style={styles.headingTextStyle}>
                                        Account Details
                                    </Text>
                                    <FormTextInputComponent           
                                         {...testID('first_name')}
                                          errorType={this.props.error.name_first.errorType}
                                          onChangeText={this.handleTextChange('name_first')}
                                          textInputRef={ref => {this.name_first = ref;}}

                                          autoCapitalize="none"
                                          spellCheck={false}
                                          autoCorrect={false}
                                          blurOnSubmit={false}
                                          onSubmitEditing={() => {
                                                    this.props.checkFieldsError('name_first', 'name_last');
                                                }}
                                            />
                                        {this.props.error.name_first.errorType ?
                                                (
                                                    <ErrorMessage textColor="#EA2027" error={error.name_first} />
                                                )
                                                : null}
//Last part 
export default fieldHOC(connect(mapStateToProps)(Account));
```

In the above component, I'm trying to call the validation function written in HOC which is `checkFieldsError`.
The problem which I'm facing is that the props passed in `<FieldValidation` like `name_first` are accessible in HOC's render function but same props are not accessible in the class functions of HOC.

Most probably what I tried to do is an antipattern in React(my guess). Can someone can please help me in figuring out the problem and the proper way to do it?

Edit: Sample implemented in codesandbox [Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/q4l783qq6)

Comment: Why you are using `fieldHOC` with View?

Comment: @RachidRhafour I tried to pass Componet which is named `Account` but I get error: Element type is invalid, expected a string or a class function but got undefined.

Comment: What kind of error you get?

Comment: Now you are using the HOC twice one with the component that doesn't have any props of what you are using in the HOC and with Account which probably has those props.

Comment: @RachidRhafour well then how should I use it?

Comment: Could you please reproduce the problem in https://codesandbox.io/s/new ?

Comment: @Totoro I created a codesandbox example for you https://codesandbox.io/s/xl0rrx26zw it works as expected, please check and tell me if that's what you are looking for

Comment: @MohamedRamrami Here https://codesandbox.io/s/q4l783qq6
I console logged the props in render of HOC and class function of HOC

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [codeSandBox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/xl0rrx26zw) I have created with what you are trying to achieve, you will notice that inside the HOC I try to access the props in its functions, also check the console to see the console logs, please check the code and follow the same example. You will achieve the same results.